# Passthrough clicks, events from Child View Controller to Parent View Controller

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I have some buttons in Child View Controller. I'd like a user to be able to click on these buttons, and, in case he clicks in other area, Parent View Controller to be able to process those clicks that Child View Controller doesn't work with.

Comment: do you mean to show the child view controller on top of the parent view controller, and if user clicks outside the buttons the child view controller should close?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create protocols and delegates.

```
protocol Vc2Delegate : AnyObject {
  func buttonPressed()
}

class Vc1 : UIViewController, Vc2Delegate {
  func presentVC2() {
     let vc2 = Vc2()
     vc2.delegate = self
     present(vc2)
 }

 func buttonPressed() {
      // process vc2 button press in vc1
 }

}

class Vc2 : UIViewConttoller {

  // weak !!!!
  weak var delegate : Vc2Delegate? = nil

  func buttonInVc2Pressed() {
      // call func in vc1 from vc2
     delegate?.buttonPressed()
  }

}
```

P.S. Sorry for formatting, was wrote from iPhone.